# Providing prizes depending on user_plan and duration_days

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, conditional-statements

For a one-day journey, we have this helper working perfectly for providing the prizes depending on the user's plan.

```
  def cost_inscription
    if user_signed_in?
      case current_user.plan_id
      when 1 
        6
      when 2 
        3
      when 3 
        1
      end 
     else
        16
    end
  end
```

Presently we have a prize table (3x5) of user's plan and journey-duration: 1,2,3,4 o+ days.
How to get the inscription cost providing two variables: user_plan and journey day-duration.

*Sure that you have one good helper for this! Let me know, Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 0):

Build a constant hash describing prizes. Here duration is a key *and* the plans are stored as [hashes with a default value](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-default).

```rb
PRIZES = {
  1 => {1 => 6, 2 => 3, 3 => 1}.tap { |h| h.default = 16 },
  2 => {1 => 6, 2 => 3, 3 => 1}.tap { |h| h.default = 14 },
  3 => {1 => 6, 2 => 3, 3 => 1}.tap { |h| h.default = 12 },
  4 => {1 => 6, 2 => 3, 3 => 1}.tap { |h| h.default = 10 },
  5 => {1 => 6, 2 => 3, 3 => 1}.tap { |h| h.default = 8 }
}.freeze

def cost_inscription(duration, plan)
  PRIZES[duration][plan]
end
```

Comment: We have this values in two tables PRODUCTS { duration, prize, ... } and JOURNEY { duration, } also we can get the plan_id of the current_user. This two variables (duration, plan) can be provided to get the correspondent PRIZE. I need more help splitting this is the helper, controller and view.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. You had `cost_inscription` method that returned an integer based on one parameter. I provided the very same method rewritten to return an integer based on two parameters. How is this related to helpers, controllers, views and other rails crap?

Comment: Thanks for you help. I hope now is more clear what  i'm looking for such as a double CASE/WHEN method.for not repeating the if statements.

Answer (score -1):

**helper**

```
def inscription_pd_id(ndays)
if user_signed_in? && current_user.plan_id == 0 #SIMPATITZANT
  case ndays
  when 1
    4  
  when 2 
    8
  when 3 
    12
  when 4 
    16
  when 5 
    20        
  end
end
if user_signed_in? && current_user.plan_id == 1 #ESPORÀDIC
  case ndays
  when 1
    5  
  when 2 
    9
  when 3 
    13
  when 4 
    17
  when 5 
    21        
  end
end
if user_signed_in? && current_user.plan_id == 2 #FREQÜENT
  case ndays
  when 1
    6  
  when 2 
    10
  when 3 
    14
  when 4 
    18
  when 5 
    22        
  end
end
if user_signed_in? && current_user.plan_id == 3 #HABITUAL
  case ndays
  when 1
    7  
  when 2 
    11
  when 3 
    15
  when 4 
    19
  when 5 
    23        
  end
end
  end
```

**controller**

```
  def show

    @sortide = Sortide.friendly.find(params[:id])

    @product = Product.find(helpers.inscription_pd_id(@sortide.ndays).to_i) 

     end
```

**view**

```
<%= @sortide.ndays %>
<%= current_user.plan_id %>
<%= @product.prize %>
```

I Know that isn't marvellous but It works.
Looking for a cleaner/nicer solution.